# Database Objects are empty for Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, datasource

My list of db objects is empty when I want to use my stored procedure spTotalOverview3 (see below).

[image]

```
USE [ProdDB]
GO
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTotalOverview3]
@datefrom datetime, 
@dateto datetime

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Counter INT 
    DECLARE @tmpyear INT = year (@datefrom)
    SET @Counter=@tmpyear - 4
    SET @datefrom = dateadd(year, -4,@datefrom)
    SET @dateto = dateadd(year, -4,@dateto)

    CREATE TABLE #DestinationTable
    (
        Jaar INT,
        QTYTotaal INT,
        QTYInterventie INT,
        QTYPreventief INT,
        QTYFacility INT,
        QTYTechdefecten INT
    )

    WHILE ( @Counter <= @tmpyear)
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO #DestinationTable (Jaar,QTYTotaal,QTYInterventie,QTYPreventief,QTYFacility,QTYTechdefecten) 
         SELECT @Counter, (Interventie+Preventief+Facility+techdefecten),  Interventie,Preventief,Facility,Techdefecten FROM (

         SELECT COUNT(*) as  Interventie
         FROM interventierapport 
         WHERE ([Datum] between @datefrom and @dateto)) as a,  

         (SELECT COUNT(*) as  Preventief
         FROM Preventief 
         WHERE ([Datum] between @datefrom and @dateto) and Datum is not null) as b,

         (SELECT COUNT(*) as Facility 
         FROM Facility 
         WHERE ([Datum_Aanvraag] between @datefrom and @dateto))  as c, 

         (SELECT COUNT(*) as Techdefecten
         FROM TechDefecten 
         WHERE ([Datum Aanvraag] between @datefrom and @dateto))  as d

         SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
         SET @datefrom = dateadd(year, +1,@datefrom)
         SET @dateto = dateadd(year, +1,@dateto)
    END

     SELECT Jaar,QTYTotaal,QTYInterventie,QTYPreventief,QTYFacility,QTYTechdefecten FROM #DestinationTable

    DROP TABLE #DestinationTable
    END
```

When I execute it, I do get my data.

[image]

So what can be the issue here?

A bit more side information:
It used to work fine with other queries where I didn't need to insert values into a temp db.
So the issue might be there, but on the other hand, mysql doesn't have a problem with it, since the sp is executing fine, with the headers that I want to use as database objects.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That procedure is a horrow show, it could have been written in a single select

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using SQL Server rather than MySQL.

For the problem itself, check that the user trying to see the procedure source code has permissions to do so.

Comment: He does. It is working with other sp, and I just changed some stuff, but nothing permission wise.

Comment: @GertDeWilde What was the "some stuff" you changed?

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post: I added/needed an insert for a temp db.  So while the sql output looks ok, VS might have a problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer.

I needed to add:
IF 1=0 BEGIN
SET FMTONLY OFF
END

To the beginning of my Stored Procedure, and now it does work.
Source:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaL7fbUou7E&ab_channel=techsapphire

A strange problem that only happens when using temp tables.